# Interleave elements in a stream with separator

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is there a nice way to use Java streams to interleave elements in a stream with a separator of the same type?

```
// Expected result in is list: [1, 0, 2, 0, 3]
List<Integer> is = Stream.of(1, 2, 3).intersperse(0).collect(toList());
```

This is similar to the [`intersperse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:intersperse) function in Haskell and other functional languages.

I have seen many examples of how to join strings in a similar way but have not found any solutions for general lists.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it with flatMap, but you'll get an additional separator after the last element :

```
List<Integer> is = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3)
                            .flatMap(i -> IntStream.of(i, 0))
                            .collect(toList());
```

Here's another way, without the trailing separator :

```
List<Integer> is = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3)
                            .flatMap(i -> IntStream.of(0, i))
                            .skip(1)
                            .collect(toList());
```

This time we add the separator before each original element, and get rid of the leading separator.

Comment: +1 If you know the size `n` of the original list, you could use `.limit(2*n-1)`.

Comment: @tobias_k That's true

Comment: Thanks. But not getting a trailing separator is sort of the point. And using `limit` here makes a bit too clumsy. But it's good to also have a solution for when you want a trailing separator!

Comment: @Lii Added another approach, without the trailing separator and without limit.

Comment: That's better! It's only a bit clumsy!

Comment: This solution seems to be the least verbose and ugly so I'll accept it. But it not very readable.

Comment: @Eran not sure the compiler you used at the time of the posting, but with jdk-8/jdk-9 latest does not work. There's a `boxed` missing.

Answer (score 10):

You can do a similar thing which `Collectors.joining` does with `String`s with a little helper method:

```
static <T> Collector<T,List<T>,List<T>> intersperse(T delim) {
    return Collector.of(ArrayList::new, (l,e)-> {
        if(!l.isEmpty()) l.add(delim);
        l.add(e);
    }, (l,l2)-> {
        if(!l.isEmpty()) l.add(delim);
        l.addAll(l2);
        return l;
    });
```

then you can use it similar to `Collectors.joining(delimiter)`:

```
List<Integer> l=Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(intersperse(0));
```

produces

> [1, 0, 2, 0, 3]

Note that this is thread safe due to the way `collect` guards these operations.

---

If you don’t want to collect into a list but insert the delimiters as an intermediate stream operation you can do it this way:

```
Integer delimiter=0;
Stream.of(1, 2, 3)/** or any other stream source */
      .map(Stream::of)
      .reduce((x,y)->Stream.concat(x, Stream.concat(Stream.of(delimiter), y)))
      .orElse(Stream.empty())
      /* arbitrary stream operations may follow */
```

Comment: I like the `.map(Stream::of)` trick. Sort of like `unflatMap`.