# Java stream apply different logic to last element in a single pass

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, java-stream

I have a stream of data from database using Spring Data Jpa that needs to be Json serialized and write to a Http response, without storing in memory. This is the sample code.

```
try (Stream<Employee> dataStream = empRepo.findAllStream()) {
        response.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        PrintWriter respWriter = response.getWriter();
        respWriter.write("[");     // array begin
        dataStream.forEach(data -> {
            try {
                respWriter.write(jsonSerialize(data));
                respWriter.write(",");
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                log(e);
            }
            entityManager.detach(data);
        });
        respWriter.write("]");    // array end
        respWriter.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log(e);
    }
}
```

But this logic will write an extra *comma* after the last element. How can I not to do `respWriter.write(",");`, if it is the last element?

There are solutions with stream operators - `peek`, `reduce` etc, but what's the most optimized solution? Is there something like `Stream.hasNext()` so that I can use an `if` condition inside `forEach`?

Comment: You could turn this around and write a comma first followed by `jsonSerialize(data)`. Except for the first iteration, where you skip the comma. Use a flag to detect the first iteration.

Comment: Don’t rely on `forEach`. Use, for example `response.getWriter().write(dataStream .map(data -> jsonSerialize(data)) .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]")) );`

Comment: If you were to use Jackson, it [supports streaming](https://cassiomolin.com/2019/08/19/combining-jackson-streaming-api-with-objectmapper-for-parsing-json/#jsongenerator) and handles state, i.e. it knows when it is necessary to append a comma to the output. If you do not want to use Jackson, I would suggest wrapping the `PrintWriter` with a stateful object that mimics the Jackson API, to the extent you need, and knows to output the comma before the next element. Maybe if you added some information on `jsonSerialize()`, we could be more specific.

Comment: @Holger: One disadvantage with that solution is that you build a string storing all the output in memory, instead of streaming parts of the output without storing them.

Comment: @Lii true, but before worrying about that, I’d suggest to do performance measuring to find the real bottleneck. Or to rethink, whether converting everything into JSON is truly necessary…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd like to say that I don't think that your problem is a good fit for a single pipeline stream. You are performing side effects both with the `write` call and the `detach` call. Maybe you are better of with a normal for-loop? Or using multiple streams instead?

That being said, you can use the technique that Eran describes in an answer to this question: [Interleave elements in a stream with separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624638/interleave-elements-in-a-stream-with-separator)

```
try (Stream<Employee> dataStream = empRepo.findAllStream()) {
    response.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    PrintWriter respWriter = response.getWriter();
    respWriter.write("[");     // array begin
    dataStream.map(data -> {
        try {
            String json = jsonSerialize(data);

            // NOTE! It is confusing to have side effects like this in a stream!
            entityManager.detach(data);
            return json;
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    })
    .flatMap(json -> Stream.of(",", json))
    .skip(1)
    .forEach(respWriter::write);

    respWriter.write("]");    // array end
    respWriter.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this specific scenario, you can use `Collectors.joining`

```
printWriter.write(dataStream
   .map(this::deserializeJson)
   .peek(entityManager::detach)
   .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

However since you are performing side-effects which are discouraged in streams, and since you specifically asked about a `hasNext()` operation, and since this streaming solution would build a large string in memory, you might instead prefer converting the stream to an iterator and using an imperative loop:

```
Iterator<Employee> it = dataStream.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
  Employee data = it.next();
  ...
  // skip writing delimiter on last entry
  if (it.hasNext()){
    respWriter.write(",")
  }
}
```